I want the image to be in te middle of the title and the end of the page. What can i do?
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \title{Adviesrapport}
    \author{Stef Jansen}
    \date{\today}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{figure}[b]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 0.70\linewidth]{Fsru_independence.jpg}
\end{figure}
\maketitle
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE

Maybe this is, more or less, what you'd like to achieve?
You can play a little with the \vspace{} to optimize the vertical position
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
    \title{Adviesrapport}
    \author{Stef Jansen}
    \date{\today\\
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.70\linewidth]{Fsru_independence.jpg}
    }
\end{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{document}


It worked. Thank you!
